# How to preserve an array across multiple executions of a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rake task which I want to run daily. The rake task would return a value. Every 15 days I want to take the average of the values retured by the rake task in the last 15 days. The rake method corresponding to task:

```
class Admin::OrderQueryController < Admin::ResourceController
def get_conversion_rate
    amount = 1
    @dollars = GoogCurrency.inr_to_usd(amount)
    debugger
    if @values.size == 15
        sum = 0
        @values.each do |x|
            sum = sum + x
        end
        avg_value = sum/15
        CurrencyConversionFactor.create! :currency => "USD", :value => avg_sum
    else
        @values.push(@dollars)
        debugger
    end
end
end
```

env_setup.rake:

```
task :convert_to_dollars => :environment do
  Admin::OrderQueryController.new.get_conversion_rate
end
```

But I don't understand how and where I can declare the @values array, so that its not lost after the execution of the method.

Thanks

Comment: you would need to store the results somewhere else (file, DB, etc) and then read / average them.  There is no where in your app / class to store that data that is guaranteed to survive reboots/reloads/etc.   So it needs to be persisted.

Comment: Did you consider saving it to the database?

Comment: You could also use Memcache, if the data is really only temporary (I use this for exchange rates).

Comment: @afpel,Doon: No I had not thought abt saving in db. Will explore this